# How to limit the pages shown in the page manager to those created by the logged in user?

Tags: pages, user-roles

I am a high school teacher (not a developer by any means), and I run a small WP site for my classroom. All of my students are contributors to the site, and I use a combination of several plug-ins in order to manage their access.

When students log into the backend and visit the "All Pages" page, they can see the titles of everyone's pages, not just their own, by clicking on the filters for "All," "Published," "Drafts," etc. I would like to remove this capability.

The phenomenal plug-in, [Manage/View Your Posts Only](https://wordpress.org/plugins/manageview-your-posts-only/), has done exactly this when it comes to posts. Students are only able to see their own posts from the "All Posts" page. However, this feature does not apply to pages.

Is there a way to create this functionality for pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this code. You can hire a dev or check out this plug in: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/ It looks to have the features you need.

If you are interested in diving into the backend, the place to get started is by building custom page templates. 
Here is some good resources on page templates:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

and the code to redirect non admin users away from that page:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, User Access Manager does not offer the functionality that I am seeking. To clarify, I already use a few plugins, including the similar Advanced Access Manager, to restrict which posts and pages the students are actually able to view and edit.  I am only seeking to alter "wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page" so that it does not display the titles of pages to which they do not have access. The plug-in I mentioned does this for posts, but not for pages.

Comment: Oh I think I understand better now. I think something more like BuddyPress might work better for this sort of thing, but it sounds like your deeply nested in your setup. Let me check a few other things

Comment: All right I modified that plugin. I'm posting it on Github in a second and I'll send you a link. It works great.

Comment: Ok here it is! https://github.com/cameck/Manage-View-Your-Posts-Pages-Only

Comment: Thanks very much! For some reason, the links to "All," "Published," & "Drafts" are still present on the page. However, when I click on them, it still only returns the pages that are "Mine." This is the functionality that I really need, so the empty buttons are somewhat irrelevant. Thanks again!

Comment: Ya, I figured I'd keep it to necessity ;-). You're welcome!